# In Swift, my error sais 'UITableViewStyle.Type' does not have a member named 'Default' What do I do to fix this?

Tags: xcode, uitableview, swift

By trying a lot of different solutions, I managed to make my test-app run by simply using ".Default" as style, but is this the right solution? 
(Still in the early learning stage, trying to understand why this works, and not the other that I thought wast the right way)

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate {

    let array = ["Item1", "Item2", "Item3", "Item4"]

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{

        return array.count
    }


    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .Default, reuseIdentifier: "style")

        cell.textLabel.text = array[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }
```

Comment: You're doing it wrong, anyway... You should use cell dequeueing.

Comment: Thanks for input! I'll do that, but do you know if this is the right solution to fix my error message (in general)? And why/ why not?

Comment: Can I comment on my own questions unlimited amount of times to earn reputation?

Comment: Not sure what you mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You tried using UITableViewStyle.Default instead of UITableViewCellStyle.Default

Fix this and your error will go away.